# Can I use this Emergency Stop Switch Push Button Mushroom Push Button 4Screw Terminal_K2 for switching on and off a 4500W 220V heating element?

Tags: switches, high-voltage

Here is the link to the emergency stop switch - http://www.ebay.com/itm/NC-N-C-Emergency-Stop-Switch-Push-Button-Mushroom-Push-Button-4Screw-Terminal-K2-/272048010923?hash=item3f575336ab. Thanks.

Comment: It's CE marked hence should have full documentation i.e. a data sheet. Do some digging.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The switch is rated for 10A. 4500W @ 220V is about 20.5A, double the maximum rated current.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of this switch is to turn on/off the safety relay. If you do not intend to use safety relay, than use at least a normal contactor/relay.